# Android WebView Cannot Load Colorbox

Tags: android, android-webview, colorbox

Would any kind soul please shed some light on this issue?

I have an Android app with a `WebView` that will load my website, which is already mobile-optimised. My issue now is that I cannot load the Colorbox (A jquery lightbox) from the `WebView`. The Chrome browser on my phone can load the Colorbox without problem though.

Some obvious codes that I have already included:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { ... }
```

Any idea on what is happening that caused this problem? Been searching high and low on SO and Google to no avail.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

Add these settings to your WebView.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, the popup is still not loading the images that is supposed to show =(

Comment: Still doesn't work. Really don't understand why. It loads fine in Chrome, but not in the webview...